# sql query ambiguous column after join

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

I am using redshift to query the data
I used the following query:

```
Select tenant_name

From (

SELECT *  from fct.st_member_development as st_member_development

inner join
(SELECT *  from fct.st_contract_development) u
on  st_member_development.tenant_name =u.tenant_name and st_member_development.fk_organization_unit =u.fk_organization_unit and st_member_development.date=u.date
)
limit 5
```

for tables I am joining both of them have tenant_name column

and my query fails with the following error : ERROR: column reference "tenant_name" is ambiguous

any idea how to fix this please ?

Comment: Don't use `*`, specify your columns explicitly. And use table aliasses to qualify the columns

Comment: Have you checked if the column `tenant_name` occurs in both tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select u.tenant_name
From fct.st_member_development as st_member_development
    inner join fct.st_contract_development u
    on  st_member_development.tenant_name = u.tenant_name and                         
    st_member_development.fk_organization_unit =u.fk_organization_unit and 
    st_member_development.date=u.date
limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the simplest solution is to not use a subquery.

If you are using a subquery, then you can list the columns you need:

```
Select mc.tenant_name
from (select md.tenant_name 
      from fct.st_member_development md join
           fct.st_contract_development cd
           on md.tenant_name = cd.tenant_name and  
              md.fk_organization_unit = cd.fk_organization_unit and
              md.date = cd.date
    ) mc
limit 5;
```

(Note the use of table aliases to *simplify* writing the query.)

If the only duplicate column names are the columns used in the `JOIN`, then you can also use `USING`:

```
select mc.tenant_name
from (select *
      from fct.st_member_development md join
           fct.st_contract_development cd
           using (tenant_name, fk_organization_unit, md.date)
    ) mc
limit 5;
```

The `USING` clause prevents the duplicates from being included in the `SELECT *`.